# Yocto: QtMultimedia does not build qtmultimedia-plugin

Tags: qt, yocto

I am currently working on a Yocto build for an embedded system that needs **Qt**.
It must also have audio capabilities in the form of **gstreamer** + **alsa**.
We accomplished the first part by introducing **Qt**, **gstreamer** and all the necessary Qt plugins.

We are having troubles with alsa because the needed QtAudio plugin is, somehow, not built at all. The library I am refering to is **/usr/lib/qt5/plugins/audio/libqtaudio_alsa.so** which, for some reason does not get built.
We are currently trying to build Qt 5.6 but we have tryied with Qt 5.9 and everything works smoothly.

With Qt 5.9 we just had to add `IMAGE_INSTALL += "qtmultimedia"` for the library to show up because the `PACKAGECONFIG` for **qtmultimedia** already has **alsa** inside it (`bitbake qtmultimedia -e | grep ^PACKAGECONFIG`).

The problem with the Qt 5.6 build is that it still has alsa inside `PACKAGECONFIG` but does not build the library. With the help of Toaster we have tracked down this library as generated by `qtmultimedia-plugins` but we really do not know where to head next.

If anybody has ever had a problem similar to the one we are facing, please do not fear to comment or answer directly.

**EDIT**: Just to clear things up I have added some screenshots from Yocto's Toaster that clearly show the problem I'm facing.

The following screenshot is a build I have done previously with Qt 5.9 where `qtmultimedia-plugins` are built correctly and the library I'm seeking for is present.

[image: Older build with Qt 5.9]

The following two screenshots are the current build that I am trying to finish with qt 5.6 and where the `qtmultimedia-plugins` is built but no library is found.

[image: Newer build with Qt 5.6 with qtmultimedia-plugins correctly built]
[image: Newer build with Qt 5.6 that shows no library was inserted in the final image]

Comment: how did you verify that library is not built at all (or is the issue that it does not  end up on the image)? Does the qtmultimedia-plugins package get built by qtmultimedia recipe and does it contain the library? If you don't know where to find out, you could start by looking in packages-split directories in  [$WORKDIR](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-WORKDIR) to see what was packaged in which package.

Comment: @jku Sorry for the misscomunication on my part: the problem I am facing is that the `libqtaudio_alsa.so` file is not present in the final rootfs which I thought meant that the package has not been built and inserted in the final image. Am I wrong?
Anyway I used Toaster's web UI to determine that the **qtmultimedia-plugins** is a direct child of **qtmultimedia** and that it should create the aforementioned file.
Also, as I mentioned in the question, I have done another build with another Qt version and there the file gets to the final image.

Comment: Right, so some options are 1) plugin is not built for some reason 2) plugin is built but ends up in the wrong package 3) plugin is in correct package but that package is not included in your image. You can investigate these possibilities in $WORKDIR as I mentioned but you can also start by looking at the rootfs manifest (in your image directory): does it contain qtmultimedia-plugins package or not?

Comment: Might be a silly question but; Have you added "qtmultimedia-plugins" to IMAGE_INSTALL?

Comment: @jku I have checked the image manifest and it does indeed contain `qtmultimedia-plugins`. I have also tried to search inside my **WORKDIR** but I am not sure what to look for.

Comment: @danlor Even without explicitly adding `qtmultimedia-plugins` to the **IMAGE_INSTALL**, the package is built since it's a runtime dependency of a package I have in my build. I have also just tried to add it to my image's **IMAGE_INSTALL** but I can see that nothing else gets rebuilt and the build re-uses all the previous artifacts and just re-builds the rootfs.

Comment: I've added a few screenshots to better represent the problem I'm facing. Maybe those can help clarify things.

Comment: @Eugenio Check inisde qtmultimedia's ${WORKDIR}/deploy-rpms/<arch>/, there should be the qtmultimedia-plugins package. EDIT: OK, I hvae just checked out the screenshots, the actual problem is that the qtmultimedia-plugins (v5.6) doesn't package the library you want.

Comment: Do you have the buildhistory available? If so, grep-search in the BUILDIR/buildhistory/packages/.../qtmultimedia/ folder: `grep -nri libqtaudio_alsa.so`, and check the results that state "files-in-package.txt". This way, you can see which package actually ships the lib.

Comment: @danlor Thanks for the detailed information but I already tried that and inside `buildhistory/packages/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtmultimedia/qtmultimedia-plugins/files-in-package.txt` there is no `libqtaudio_alsa.so`. Also searching for it with grep does not yield any results.

Comment: I mean, use grep at base-level folder (qtmultimedia, not qtmultimedia-plugins), since in that version it could be packaged in other way. (just in case you haven't done it this way)

Comment: @danlor Yes, sorry for the missunderstanding, I used grep at the `qtmultimedia` level. I wrote `qtmultimedia-plugins` just because the older builds I had done all had the library built in that package so I thought it was the same.

Comment: Have you checked the compilation log under the WORKDIR?

Comment: @danlor I have, there is no trace of the library I'm seeking for. Could it be a miss-configuration of the package itself?

Comment: I have a hunch, by inspecting https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/86363/ it seems DISTRO_FEATURES += 'alsa' would work.